# Sending a raw image to my database (parse), how should I send it?

Tags: c#, image, forms, xamarin

Getting closer to solve my problem, one step at a time. I now have a raw image data and the last step is to send it to my database and in this case I use Parse. This is the code so far:

The viewmodel with the Selectpicture function and how I get the image raw (works):

```
public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();
        ImageSource = null;

        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);

            imageData = ReadStream(mediaFile.Source);

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

The page where I try to send the picture to my database and where the user can see the picture they selected, this is where I am stuck:

```
private async void btnPickPicture_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await MyViewModel.SelectPicture ();
        imgPicked.Source = MyViewModel.ImageSource; //my image x:name in xaml
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (imgPicked.Source);

    }
 //Below I send it to my parse and in parse they save it as a "File". This is the part where I am not sure how to get it right. I have to pass it as a byte but Iam not sure how to execute it.

async void SendDataClick (object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        var createResult = await parseAPI.createInfo 
            ( MyViewModel.ImageData );
    }
```

Code to parse:

```
static public async Task<bool> createInfo (byte [] thePicture)
```

Comment: Totally a side note : In case you have not heard, Facebook is shutting down Parse, so for new development you might want to think about another service... http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Yes I know. But as I am mostly trying to learn now I use it for my exercise projects.

Answer (score 0):

use [ParseFile](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#files) for saving images and binary data

```
// pass the ImageData from your VM into the constructor
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.jpg", MyViewModel.ImageData);

// save the file
file.SaveAsync();
```

Comment: I use parse via REST API so that would not work for my particular case I think.

Comment: So I need to send an URL or something? Experimenting a bit but coming no where.

Comment: My parse database is setup, I just need to send it the correct way inside my: SendDataClick function (the last piece of code)

Comment: Trying to send it like this: ( MyViewModel.ImageData ); But as I have it as an ImageSource in my parseprofile, i cannot send it as byte as it requires an image